# How to change match modifier within a program in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$text =~ /"helloworld"/g
```

I want to have this regex modifdier 'g' into a variable so that later I can change it to a different modifier like this 'i', 's' so on

e.g.

```
$text="helloworld"
$test="helloworld"
$modifier="g"

$text =~ /$test/$modifier
```

Comment: does the above works or not?

Comment: I want to use it like this, it is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238348/how-to-use-a-variable-as-modifier-in-a-substitution

Comment: That linked question only has awful answers :(

Comment: It makes no sense to add `g` dynamically on a match?!?